# "Don’t use products that are not ____ if you want to protect our planet." (ENVIRONMENT)

Tags: exam-questions

> Don’t use products that are not ____ if you want to protect our planet. (ENVIRONMENT)

This is a word formation question. I can't find the suitable form of the word 'environment' given above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most common terms for things which do not harm the environment are:

- Environmentally friendly
- Ecologically sound

Example:

> Don't use products that are not environmentally friendly if you want to protect our planet.

Ideally, you should remove the double negative ("don't... not") from your sentence by changing it to:

> *Use* products that *are* environmentally friendly if you want to protect our planet.

If you really want to retain the warning "don't", you could change it around by saying:

> Don't use products *that harm the environment* if you want to protect our planet.